# Solve ill-posed linear system without transposing matrices?

Tags: least-squares, linear-system

I am attempting to use an iterative solver to solve $p$ in

$$
Jp = -r
$$

where $J$ is an $m\times m$ matrix ($m$ is in the order of $10^5$ and never explicitly stored). $J$ is a dense matrix representing a Jacobian for a certain function, and, in general, is not symmetric.

Unfortunately, this is an ill-posed problem and possibly infinite versions of $p$ exist.

I cannot compute the least-squares version

$$
J^TJp=J^Tr
$$

because I only can access the product of $Jp$ and not $J^Tp$ (a limitation of an automatic differentiation approach I am taking).

- Is there a way I can compute $p$ in $Jp = -r$ according to some criterion (e.g. least-squares solution) without transposing
  $J$?
- If I use an iterative solver (e.g. GMRES, BiCGStab, etc...) with an
  initial guess of $p=0$, what solution will the solver converge to?
  The minimum-norm?

Comment: is $J$ sparse? if so, are you familiar with the [MINRES](http://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/minres/) family of solvers? if you're looking for the min-length solution, then [MINRES-QLP](http://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/minresqlp/) may be a good option for your problem.

Comment: as a side-comment, why is automatic differentiation limiting your options when it comes to $J^T$? If $J$ is the Jacobian of some $m$-variable (and at least locally smooth) function $f$, then reverse-mode AD gives you $J^T p$ for any direction $p$.

Comment: Independently of the question of what solver to use, it is important to ask whether $r$ is in the image space of $J$? Because, if it is not, then whatever solver you use will not converge to a solution of $Jp=-r$ because the equation does not have a solution.

Comment: The MINRES methods require $A$ to be symmetric (in which case all methods are effectively transpose free...)

Comment: @GoHokies Reverse-mode AD requires excessive memory in my application. Beyond the point of being reasonably used.

Comment: @bfletch Disk checkpointing with something like Griewank's [_revolve_](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=347837.347846) (or one of [its on-line variants](https://web.stanford.edu/group/ctr/ResBriefs08/4_checkpointing.pdf)) should lower the memory requirements of reverse-mode AD.

Comment: Regarding your original problem, what have you tried so far? Just how well is GMRES doing? Are you using some kind of preconditioner? There are also other solvers worth looking into - one example is TFQMR (where `TF` stands for _transpose-free_ - see chapter 7.4 of [Saad's book](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/toc.pdf)).

Comment: @GoHokies I've looked into checkpointing. Unfortunately, my problem is just not well suited for reverse-mode in any fashion... at least with the current state of the tools and language I'm using.

Comment: Just looked at that book. Thanks for the recommendation, great resource. I haven't actually implemented this yet, just planning ahead. I plan on using a preconditioner, but not sure what yet. I guess any of the methods mentioned that chapter would work, but I'd like to know what solution is converged to in the case of an ill-posed problem if any.

Comment: FYI, I found an [awesome paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.03679.pdf) put on arxiv a few days ago that explores my question.

Comment: as (another) side-question, what is the source of the rank-deficiency (or ill-posedness) of your Jacobian?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65927/discussion-between-gohokies-and-bfletch).